# Probabilistic model: what's the probability of this model?

Tags: probability, inference, conditional-probability, model

[image]

The above model is from [Berkeley cs294-112 Page 23](http://rail.eecs.berkeley.edu/deeprlcourse/static/slides/lec-15.pdf). It is said that
$$
p(O_{1:T},s_{1:T}, a_{1:T}) =p(s_1)\prod_{t}p(s_{t+1}|s_t,a_t)p(O_t|s_t,a_t)\tag 1
$$

I'm quite confused about this solution: where is $p(a_t|s_t)$?

I'm thinking whether this has something to do with the assumption that $p(a_t|s_t)$ is a uniform distribution, but it uses $=$ instead of $\propto$ and the result is further used in the computation of the Evidence Lower Bound. How is Eq.(1) derived?

Comment: can you point us to the page you saw this formula?

Comment: @gunes It is in Page 23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I can get for now, welcome to comment.

The probability model is 
$$
p(O_{1:T},s_{1:T},a)=p(s_1)\prod_tp(s_{t+1}|s_t,a_t)p(O_t|s_t,a_t)p(a_t|s_t)
$$ 
taking logarithm, we have
$$
\log p(O_{1:T},s_{1:T},a)=\log p(s_1)+\sum_t\log p(s_{t+1}|s_t,a_t)+\log p(O_t|s_t,a_t)+\log p(a_t|s_t)
$$
because $p(a_t|s_t)$ is uniform, the last term is a constant term. This means it does not contribute to the discussion about the ELBO, so the instructor omitted it for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

It seems they assume (for simplicity) that $ p(a_t|s_t) $ is uniform (they explicitly say so in page 9 (Backward messages)), as you said, and therefore its density function is $ f(a_t|s_t) = 1 $ (they assumed standard uniform), and since it is 1 it disappears from the formula.

Comment: I know that $p(a_t|s_t)$ is uniform, but what is $f(a_t|s_t)$?

Comment: If $ a_t $ is a continuous random variable, then $ p(a_t) $ is always 0. It is common in papers to write $ p(x) $ as a general notation, that refers to the probability if it is discrete and to density ($f(x)$) if it is continuous. In this case since it is continuous, by $p$ they actually mean $f$ (density function).

Comment: Hi, @Orielno. Thanks for your clarification. But I still do not understand why you said that the density function of a uniform distribution was 1? What do you think $p(O_{1:T}, s_{1:T}, a_{1:T})$ would be if we did not ignore anything?

Comment: Then it would be as you said, we would add $ p(a_t | s_t) $